# Calling function from BLL layer to controller in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlist

public class StudentBLL
    {

```
        StudentDAL objStudent = new StudentDAL();
        public List<StudentDAL> GetAllStudnets() {

            List<StudentDAL > lstStudents = objStudent.GetStudentList().Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(
                        dataRow => new StudentDAL 
                        {
                            StuID = dataRow.Field<int>("StudentId"),
                            StuName = dataRow.Field<int>("StudentName")
                        }).ToList();

            return lstStudents;
        }

    }
```

I want to call this function in my Home Controller:

```
    public JsonResult LoadStudents(int randomJunk)
    {
        //call function here ??
        List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //selectListItems.Add(si);
       // selectListItems.Add(si1);

        var notesTypes = new SelectList(selectListItems, "Value", "Text");

        return Json(notesTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

So how can call the return list to my Home Controller , I'm really confused and I'm not a student

Comment: `StudentBLL  obj = new StudentBLL (); List<StudentDAL> ls = obj.GetAllStudnets();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of class StudentBLL and call the method `GetAllStudnets` with this object

```
StudentBLL  obj = new StudentBLL ();
List<StudentDAL> ls = obj.GetAllStudnets();
```

Best practise is to create an interface with the required methods. create a class which implements the method. Use dependency injection to inject the class in the controller to call the method.

Comment: Okay, thank you, where I should implement the interfaces? In BLL layer or seperately?